# starting/stopping while loops with button in tkinter

Tags: python, class, user-interface, tkinter, while-loop

By using two different buttons, I'm trying to start and stop a process based on a while loop that scans through patterns (actually just counting in this example). In the following code, I have tried to simplify and generalise the more complex process that occurs in the actual project I'm working on. As you can see by running the code, you can start the count by pressing the play button; when you press the stop button though, the process doesn't stop immediately. I have previously managed to make it work as desired, but while rewriting the code with an object oriented approach, nothing is working properly anymore. At the moment, I can't understand anymore if the problem is in the while loop construction or if I'm working with threads in the wrong way.
Any suggestion is very welcome and appreciated!

```
from tkinter import *
import threading
import time

class gui:

    def __init__(self, window):

        #play button
        self.play_frame = Frame (master = window, relief = FLAT, borderwidth = 1)
        self.play_frame.grid (row = 0, column = 0, padx = 1, pady = 1)
        self.play_button = Button (self.play_frame, text = "play", fg = "blue", command = lambda: self.play(1))
        self.play_button.pack()
        #stop button
        self.stop_frame = Frame (master = window, relief = FLAT, borderwidth = 1)
        self.stop_frame.grid (row = 0, column = 2, padx = 1, pady = 1)
        self.stop_button = Button (self.stop_frame, text = "stop", fg = "red", command = lambda: self.play(0))
        self.stop_button.pack()

    def process(self, trig):
        self.trig = trig

        while True:
            if self.trig == 1:

                for i in range (10):
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    print (i)


            elif self.trig == 0:
                print ("stopped...")
                break

    def play(self, switch):


        self.switch = int(switch)
        t1 = threading.Thread (target = self.process, args = [self.switch], daemon = True)
        t1.start()
        

root = Tk()

app = gui(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: do you want the counter to start again? every time you press stop

Comment: You are starting a new thread instead of stopping the old one. I could show you how to fix it but I think you have oversimplified your question. For example, what's the point of the trig variable? Do you need multiple threads? Did you want to interrupt the 10-count (your current code only stops the outer loop)?

Comment: Yes, I would need multiple threads. I'm trying to implement a step sequencer and ideally I would have multiple "tracks" and so multiple threads. The trig variable is used to trigger a pattern scanning process (right now I'm just "counting", but I'm going to read a pattern that is like pattern = [1, 0,  0, 1...]). @coderoftheday not necessarily, but since the application I have described should be used in real time I will need to have the whole process to be "re -triggered" on update of certain variables. Also pressing play should restart the sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a separate thread that receives a signal when to start and stop the countdown

```
from tkinter import *
import threading
import time


should_run = False
class a:
    def __init__(self):
        while True:
            if should_run:
                for i in range(10):
                    if not should_run:
                        print('Stopped...')
                        break
                    if should_run:
                        time.sleep(0.5)
                        print(i)

t1 = threading.Thread(target=a,daemon=True)
t1.start()

class gui:

    def __init__(self, window):

        # play button
        self.play_frame = Frame(master=window, relief=FLAT, borderwidth=1)
        self.play_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)
        self.play_button = Button(self.play_frame, text="play", fg="blue", command=lambda: self.play(True))
        self.play_button.pack()
        # stop button
        self.stop_frame = Frame(master=window, relief=FLAT, borderwidth=1)
        self.stop_frame.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=1, pady=1)
        self.stop_button = Button(self.stop_frame, text="stop", fg="red", command=lambda: self.play(False))
        self.stop_button.pack()


    def play(self, switch):
        global should_run
        should_run = switch



root = Tk()

app = gui(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks! this certainly works as expected, I will try to implent the procedure you have  suggested in the bigger project and see if it's going to work.

Comment: no worries, its the same logic, create a thread that contains a counter and waits for signals to stop or start

Comment: I have tried to adapt the same logic to my project and the program runs as expected. Things stop working properly though when I put the classes in separate files to make the code easier to read. The process in the thread seems to be unresponsive to the buttons' input. I will post an example if I manage to replicate the situation...

Comment: I think one error could happen in the situation that I have just described in the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65079415/why-pressing-tkinter-buttons-wont-update-the-global-variable