# triggering and stopping a process with tkinter buttons

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, callback, python-multithreading

(*scroll down for the edited version of this question*)

I expect the variable "a", made *global* in the "play" callback function, to update every time I press the "play" or "stop" buttons. As you can see by running the code, the callback function update its value whenever I press the buttons, but if a try to test the value of the global variable within the tkinter mainloop, I only get it updated only when the program is started.

```
from tkinter import *

a = 0

class gui:

    def __init__(self, window):

        # play button
        self.play_frame = Frame(master=window, relief=FLAT, borderwidth=1)
        self.play_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)
        self.play_button = Button(self.play_frame, text="play", fg="blue", command=lambda: self.play(1))
        self.play_button.pack()
        # stop button
        self.stop_frame = Frame(master=window, relief=FLAT, borderwidth=1)
        self.stop_frame.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=1, pady=1)
        self.stop_button = Button(self.stop_frame, text="stop", fg="red", command=lambda: self.play(0))
        self.stop_button.pack()


    def play(self, switch):
        global a
        a = switch
        print (a)

root = Tk()

if a == 1:
    print ("one")
elif a == 0:
    print ("zero")

app = gui(root)
root.mainloop()
```

EDIT 1:

I have written the code again in order to make the question clearer and in order to simulate what's going on in the situation I'm trying to reproduce with these simplified examples. I expect the tester function to print out "running" or "not running" according to each button I press. I'm running "tester" inside a thread because in the acutal project I'm working on "tester" is a way more complex process:

```
from tkinter import *
import threading
import time

a = 0

class gui:

    def __init__(self, window):

        # play button
        self.play_frame = Frame(master=window, relief=FLAT, borderwidth=1)
        self.play_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)
        self.play_button = Button(self.play_frame, text="play", fg="blue", command=lambda: self.play(1))
        self.play_button.pack()
        # stop button
        self.stop_frame = Frame(master=window, relief=FLAT, borderwidth=1)
        self.stop_frame.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=1, pady=1)
        self.stop_button = Button(self.stop_frame, text="stop", fg="red", command=lambda: self.play(0))
        self.stop_button.pack()


    def play(self, switch):
        global a
        a = switch
        print (a)

root = Tk()

def tester(trig):
    while True:


        if trig == 1:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print ("running")
        elif trig == 0:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print ("not running")
    


t1 = threading.Thread (target = tester, args = [a], daemon = True)
t1.start()

app = gui(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm confused,  the variable doesn't change when you press the button?

Comment: Add a third button that just prints out the value. You'll see that it _is_ being changed.  Also, it's generally considered bad practice to use global variables with classes.

Comment: I have edited the previous question to make the problem easier to understand, the original formulation was indeed unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a primitive type to a function is using `pass by value`, so the following line:

```
t1 = threading.Thread (target = tester, args = [a], daemon = True)
```

will pass the value of `a` (since `a` is of primitive type `int`) to `tester` which is `0`.

You can use `IntVar` instead for `a`, so that `pass by reference` is used:

```py
from tkinter import *
import threading
import time

class gui:
    def __init__(self, window):
        # play button
        self.play_frame = Frame(master=window, relief=FLAT, borderwidth=1)
        self.play_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)
        self.play_button = Button(self.play_frame, text="play", fg="blue", command=lambda: self.play(1))
        self.play_button.pack()
        # stop button
        self.stop_frame = Frame(master=window, relief=FLAT, borderwidth=1)
        self.stop_frame.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=1, pady=1)
        self.stop_button = Button(self.stop_frame, text="stop", fg="red", command=lambda: self.play(0))
        self.stop_button.pack()

    def play(self, switch):
        a.set(switch) # update 'a'
        print(a.get())

root = Tk()

a = IntVar(value=0)

def tester(trig):
    while True:
        value = trig.get()
        if value == 1:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print ("running")
        elif value == 0:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print ("not running")

t1 = threading.Thread (target = tester, args = [a], daemon = True)
t1.start()

app = gui(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

that if statement is only being run once, if you want to print out **one** or **two**
everytime you press a button, I'd suggest putting the if statement inside the **play** function.

```
from tkinter import *

a = 0

class gui:

    def __init__(self, window):

        # play button
        self.play_frame = Frame(master=window, relief=FLAT, borderwidth=1)
        self.play_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)
        self.play_button = Button(self.play_frame, text="play", fg="blue", command=lambda: self.play(1))
        self.play_button.pack()
        # stop button
        self.stop_frame = Frame(master=window, relief=FLAT, borderwidth=1)
        self.stop_frame.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=1, pady=1)
        self.stop_button = Button(self.stop_frame, text="stop", fg="red", command=lambda: self.play(0))
        self.stop_button.pack()


    def play(self, switch):
        global a
        a = switch
        
        if a == 1:
            print ("one")
        elif a == 0:
            print ("zero")

root = Tk()

app = gui(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You also can delete 'global a' if that is its only function

Comment: I have posted an edit to my original question to make the question easier to understand, but thanks for this first answer, it actually opened up a perspective on a possible solution to the problem.